# DB2 Create Table X when X is a variable?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

In Oracle, we do this:

```
def TNAME=&1
create table &TNAME (foo varchar(10));
```

How to do the equivalent for DB2?  The constraints are:

```
1. The create table statement is generated when TNAME is unknown
2. The create table statement is in a file which cannot be modified
3. Cannot create a temporary file with TNAME substituted by awk
4. Essentially we want to pass in the table name at run time as an argument
```

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000950.html) statement can be used in just about any block of SQL that is surrounded by a BEGIN and END, such as a stored procedure or anonymous compound statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE create_table_from_file( IN fileDir VARCHAR( 1024 ), 
                                         IN fileName VARCHAR( 128 ),
                                         IN tabSchema VARCHAR( 128 ),
                                         IN tabName VARCHAR( 128 )
                                        )
BEGIN
DECLARE fh UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
DECLARE sqlStmt VARCHAR( 32672 );
DECLARE currentLine VARCHAR( 32672 );
DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE SQLSTATE1 CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE 'ORANF' SET SQLSTATE1 = SQLSTATE;

SET sqlStmt = 'CREATE TABLE ' 
    || CASE WHEN ( NULLIF( tabSchema, '' ) IS NOT NULL ) 
       THEN RTRIM( tabSchema ) || '.'
       ELSE '' END || tabName;
CALL UTL_DIR.CREATE_OR_REPLACE_DIRECTORY( 'createTablePath', fileDir );
SET fh = UTL_FILE.FOPEN( 'createTablePath', fileName, 'r' );
loop1: LOOP
    CALL UTL_FILE.GET_LINE( fh, currentLine );
    IF SQLSTATE1 = 'ORANF' THEN -- NO DATA FOUND
        LEAVE loop1;
    END IF;
    SET sqlStmt = sqlStmt || ' ' || currentLine ;
END LOOP;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlStmt;
END
@
```

Comment: does this address the 4 constraints? esp. the part about passing in the file name as a variable?  the only way i could find was my own answer below and i am not sure if execute immediate is a solution or a better solution. i'll be happy to accept your answer if it is indeed a solution. thanks :)

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how a stored procedure could handle the table name and DDL file as parameters.

Comment: ummm... this is complicated. This answer has the positive over mine that it does not rely on 'sed' or a Unix environment. It relies on DB2 file i/o whereas mine puts the file mechanism outside of DB2's scope. All said and done I still prefer my own answer but since there's a conflict of interest I am accepting your answer because it is definitely valid :)  This note is mainly to let readers compare it with my answer below before deciding on what to do in practice (depending on whether they have a Unix environment or not).

Comment: Thanks. The sed approach is elegant, as long as the DDL is being run from a proper DB2 client interpreter on a Linux/UNIX OS. The example I posted demonstrates the file-reading features that were introduced in DB2 9.7 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows.

Comment: just one more question -- would this work on z/OS too?  A lot of DB2 installations run on z/OS due to their both being IBM preferred platforms. If this works for z/OS it would be the ideal way! Thanks again!

Comment: The EXECUTE IMMEDIATE part will work on DB2 for z/OS, but the UTL_FILE routines that handle the file I/O are only supported on DB2 LUW for now.

Comment: Thanks for that final clarification!

Answer (score 0):

I created a file `abc` containing:

```
create table TNAME (foo varchar(10))
```

Then I did, on a Unix command-line:

```
sed s/TNAME/xyz/g abc | db2
```

which created a table called `xyz` in DB2 as I wanted. Thanks.