# Create table in a loop with a variable value in DB2

Tags: sql, loops, db2, create-table

I need to create tables with a name like YEAR_(here goes a variable value)

I have a table with year numbers (2010,2012,2014). I want to take those and create the tables YEAR_2010, YEAR_2012 and YEAR_2014.

This need to be done within a loop.

I tried to do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_YEAR 
   (    YEAR_COLUMN integer
   );


INSERT INTO temp_year
  ( year_column )
  ( 
    select extract(year from datum) from datetest
  );

BEGIN 
 FOR vl AS
c1 cursor for
   SELECT  year_column FROM temp_year
     DO

     EXEC SQL execute immediate  'create table YEAR_' || year_column || ' (year integer, name varchar2(50));
 END FOR;


   END;
/

drop table temp_year;
```

The first create is working so is the insert. The rest is messing up.

It starts with this error message (translated from german):

```
 EXEC SQL execute immediate  'create table YEAR_' || year_column || ' (year integer, name varchar2(50))
DB21034E SQL statement is wrong.
SQL0104N  On "          EXEC" follows the invalid Token "SQL".  Allowed tokens could be: ":".  LINE NUMBER=7.  SQLSTATE=42601
```

The goal is to create the tables with the help of those year numbers.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To me it doesn't sound like a good design to have a separate table for every year.  It would be better to just have one table with a field for the year.  Then use an SQL statement to gather the information you require.

Comment: I need those year tables. They need to be back-uped like that. Those are huge tables on themselves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DB2 Create Table X when X is a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696351/db2-create-table-x-when-x-is-a-variable)

Comment: If so how can I get this to work with the select for the cursor? With the select I have the numbers I need, how do i pass them on the the sql statement?

Answer (score 1):

Where is this `EXEC SQL` thing coming from? The statement is just `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/r0055453.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok 1 Problem I just go to know today is that PL/SQL is disabled and has to stay like that so here is how it works for me now:

(Change the ending indicator to @)

Only once to get the temp table:

```
  CREATE TABLE TEMP_YEAR 
   (    YEAR_COLUMN NUMBER
   )@
```

Here is the Procedure

```
 CREATE or replace PROCEDURE Year_tab_create ()
     LANGUAGE SQL
 BEGIN
 DECLARE sqlStmt VARCHAR( 32672 );
 DECLARE v_numRecords INT DEFAULT 1;
 DECLARE v_year INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE v_counter INT DEFAULT 0;

 DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
   select year_column from temp_year;


 INSERT INTO temp_year
  ( year_column )
  ( 
    select distinct extract(year from datum) from datetest
  );

 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_numRecords  FROM temp_year;

 OPEN c1;
 WHILE v_counter < (v_numRecords)
 DO
   FETCH c1 INTO v_year;
   set sqlStmt =  'create table YEAR_' || v_year || ' (year integer, name varchar(50))';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlStmt;
  SET v_counter = v_counter + 1;
 END WHILE; 
 CLOSE c1;
delete from temp_year;
END
@
```

Hope this maybe helps someone else too.